# Can I provision my Elastic Beanstalk's EC2 instance with Cloud Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I was wondering if I am able to provision my EB's EC2 instance in Cloud Formation? The main reason I want to do this is that I want to run `nvidia-docker` on my EC2 instance, but I believe the EC2 instances provided don't have it.

I know that I can create an provision AMI in Cloud Formation, then use that AMI as the image for my EB, but since I only need to install `nvidia-docker`, as I'm going to be deploying container anyways it seems like a bit of an overkill. I would much rather just run the few commands to install `nvidia-docker` instead of waiting for an AMI to save.

Comment: If you want to create the EC2 instance and install some software after creation, that's perfectly doable with CloudFormation. However, if you want just install nvidia-docker in an existent instance, you could use Ansible or even a simple script. Using Cloud Formation seems a bit overengineered.

Comment: This is a step of our CICD pipeline after we use CodeBuild to create our Docker image which is uploaded to ECR. I'm just a bit confused about how to provision my EB application as I've looked through the docs, and it seems like they all require a source bundle stored in a S3 bucket. Though if my application is already in a Docker container, do I just create a new S3 bucket with an empty application zip file? Also, I can't figure out how to provision my EB's EC2 and to pull down an image from ECR using CloudFormation. Any ideas?